# Mean survival time for a Gamma survival function

Tags: survival, mean, gamma-distribution, median

I was not able to find the formula to allow me to calculate the mean and the median survival time for a Gamma survival function.

Does anyone knows how to calculate these?

Answer (score 7):

In my parametrisation (take $\lambda = 1 / \theta$ to obtain the same parametrisation as in the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Median_calculation)), the density function is
$$
f(t) = \frac{\lambda^k t^{k-1} \exp(-\lambda t)}{\Gamma(k)} \qquad (\lambda > 0, \,k > 0)
$$
with
$$
\Gamma(k) = \int_0^\infty x^{k-1} \exp(-x) \, \textrm{d}x
$$
Thus,
$$
\textrm{E}(T) = \int_0^\infty t f(t) \, \textrm{dt} = \frac{k}{\lambda}
$$

The median survival time is found by solving $S(t) = 1 / 2$ for $t$. However, there is no explicit formula for the median survival time. Indeed, the survival function is
$$
S(t) = 1 - \frac{\int_0^{\lambda t} s^{k-1} \exp(-s)\, \textrm{d}s}{\Gamma(k)}
$$
The integral that appears in the formula for $S(t)$ is called the incomplete gamma integral (see [the handbook of mathematical functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf), section 6.5) which has no closed form expression. The solution to the equation $S(t) = 1 / 2$ can however be approached numerically.

Comment: +1 - good to have discussion of the numerical solution of the median.

Answer (score 5):

If the survival time has a Gamma distribution, the median survival time doesn't have a simple closed form (but see below).

The mean depends on your parameterization.

If $\alpha$ is the shape parameter, and $\beta$ the scale parameter, then the mean survival is $\alpha \beta$; alternatively, if $\alpha$ is the shape parameter, and $\theta$ the *rate* parameter, then the mean survival is $\alpha/\theta$.

My parameterizations are backwards to what Wikipedia has. (Or at least has now ... I believe mine are consistent with how it used to be.) 
They have $\theta$ for the scale and $\beta$ for the rate.

(Often - but not always - survival models will be parameterized in the second form, with $\lambda$ - as the rate parameter - written as a function of predictors.)

**Approximation to the median survival**:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Median_calculation) gives an approximation to the median: $\mu \frac{3 \alpha - 0.8}{3 \alpha + 0.2}$ where $\mu$ is the mean survival time. This approximation is not suitable if $\alpha <1$. The paper for this is findable online via Google.